# Comparator: How to use nullsFirst and stream api?

Tags: lambda, java-8, comparator, nullable

I'm struggling to write a `Comparator` that handles null fields.

I have pojo like this:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@Data
@Builder
public class Pojo implements Comparable<Pojo> {
  private Integer id;
  private BigDecimal cost;

  private static final Comparator<Pojo> COMPARATOR =
      comparingInt((Pojo p) -> p.id).thenComparing(p -> p.cost);

  @Override
  public int compareTo(@NotNull Pojo pojo) {
    return COMPARATOR.compare(this, pojo);
  }
}
```

And some tests:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

class PojoShould {

  private static final int SMALLER = -1;
  private static final int LARGER = 1;
  private static final int EQUAL = 0;

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource
  void compareToWorks(Pojo p1, Pojo p2, int expectedResult) {
    assertThat(p1.compareTo(p2)).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  static Stream<Arguments> compareToWorks() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(Pojo.builder().id(-1).build(), Pojo.builder().id(0).build(), SMALLER),
        Arguments.of(Pojo.builder().id(0).build(), Pojo.builder().id(-1).build(), LARGER),
        Arguments.of(Pojo.builder().id(0).build(), Pojo.builder().id(0).build(), EQUAL),
        Arguments.of(
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ZERO).build(),
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ONE).build(),
            SMALLER),
        Arguments.of(
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ONE).build(),
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ZERO).build(),
            LARGER),
        Arguments.of(
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ZERO).build(),
            Pojo.builder().id(0).cost(BigDecimal.ZERO).build(),
            EQUAL));
  }
}
```

Most cases works but the one where the ids are equal and it tries to compare the `null` cost (of course).

How do I make the Comaparator null safe? I've tried

```
  private static final Comparator<Pojo> COMPARATOR =
      nullsFirst(comparingInt((Pojo p) -> p.id))
          .thenComparing(nullsFirst(comparing((p -> p.cost))));
```

but that does not help.

Comment: can you filter out null objects before comparing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation of [`Comparator#thenComparing(Function,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)):

> Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that extracts a key to be compared with the given `Comparator`.
>
> **Implementation Requirements:**
>
> This default implementation behaves as if `thenComparing(comparing(keyExtractor, cmp))`.

Which references [`Comparator#comparing(Function,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)):

> Accepts a function that extracts a sort key from a type `T`, and returns a `Comparator<T>` that compares by that sort key using the specified `Comparator`.
>
> The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function and comparator are both serializable.

As stated by the documentation, it's the `Comparator` argument that's used to compare the values extracted by the `Function`. This means it's *that* `Comparator` that must be capable of handling `null`. This is opposite of what you appear to be trying to do.

One way to make a `null`-safe `Comparator`, without having to write the code manually, is to use either [`Comparator#nullsFirst(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) or [`Comparator#nullsLast(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)). Both those methods wrap another `Comparator` that, if both elements to be compared are non-`null`, will be invoked. Basically, the  `Comparator` returned by `nullsFirst` or `nullsLast` is an interceptor.

Now all that's needed is the `Comparator` that will be wrapped by the `null`-safe `Comparator`. Since both `Integer` and `BigDecimal` are `Comparable`, we can use [`Comparator#naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()).

Assuming both `id` and `cost` can be `null`, and that you want `null` values to be first in each case, then following should work for you:

```
comparing(p -> p.id, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(p -> p.cost, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));
```

Or, if you assume that `id` will never be `null`, you can modify the above like so:

```
comparing(p -> p.id)
        .thenComparing(p -> p.cost, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));
```